# URL of an image that can seen in browser from firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am creating a iOS swift application that uses an SDK that requires a link to image that can be seen in browser for example http://i.imgur.com/HALb2yN.jpg is acceptable as it does not automatically download.

However for firebase the download URL I get using the code:

```
let imageRef = String(format: "images/%@", file.identifier)
let testRef = storageRef.child(imageRef)

let uploadTask = testRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
    if (error != nil) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
        print(downloadURL)
    }
}
```

from **downloadURL** automatically downloads... I would like to be able to get a link that can be viewed in the from a browser. Is that possible with firebase?

Comment: The download URL is a direct link to the image data. Are you looking for a web page instead that then contains the image?

Comment: Yes for example Instagram, Facebook and Twitter provides such a page. I do not think Google Drive or Dropbox does this (not 100% sure) and I would like to upload the images from these services to firebase to rectify the problem. Basically the SDK I am using requires a webpage that contains the image and only the image e.g. Google Drive has its interface around the image in the URL it provides that can be seen in the browser.

Comment: Did you consider building a static web page (for example on Firebase Hosting) that you then pass the download URL into? E.g. `https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/image.html?downloadUrl=...`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you haven't set any metadata with the image. Therefore Firebase (and your browser) doesn't know that your mystery binary object is an image that can be displayed in-browser instead of some other file that needs to be downloaded.

Try creating a metadata object with the appropriate content-type and use that in your putData call, and I betcha that'll work.